# how to change server collation in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008, collation

how do I change the server collation setting from 'Chinese_PRC_CI_AS' to 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is not an easy process, according to this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx

If it's possible, I'd recommend just changing the collation for each database, per this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx

Comment: thanks for the resource. it's useful. i found the date format in my friend format is yyyy-mm-dd, and his collation is Chinese. However mine is dd/mm/yyyy.  is it the collation setting issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the collation of "master" database/Server by rebuilding the database, for this go through to these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207003(v=sql.100).aspx

http://sqlbuzz.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/how-to-rebuild-master-database-aka-rebuilding-sql-server-2008r2/

but make sure you backup all your database before doing this.